# Numbering equations in tabular environment

Tags: tables, equations, numbering, inline

I wish to number equations in a table, like numbering them in

```
\begin{equation}.
    ...
\end{equation}
```

Since all the equations are written as "inline" equations (for example, `$a = b+c$`) in `tabular` environment, I have no idea how to number them. Can you help me to find out a way?

Comment: are you sure you want a table rather than a numbered equation environment such as `amsmath` `align`? If you do want a table the simplest is to use \begin{equation} in a `p` column, or if you do want to number inline expressions just go `\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)` whereever you want the number.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  For future reference, please keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 6):

I answered a similar question at the [German community MrUnix](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=71637):

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\tagarray}{%
\mbox{}\refstepcounter{equation}%
$(\theequation)$%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{1}
\end{equation}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lrcl>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
Anode: & $\frac{1}{2}O_{2}+2e^{-}$ & $\longrightarrow$ & $O^{2-}$ & \tagarray\label{2}\\
Kathode: & $H_{2}+O^{2-}$ & $\longrightarrow$ & $H_{2}O+2e^{-}$ &\tagarray\label{3}\\
Gesamtreaktion: & $H_{2}+\frac{1}{2}O_{2}$ & $\longrightarrow$ & $H_{2}O$ &\tagarray\label{4}
\end{tabularx}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{5}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\ref{1}\qquad\ref{2}\qquad\ref{3}\qquad\ref{4}\qquad\ref{5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do we do it without cheating? I mean without \ref{1}\qquad\ref{2}\qquad\ref{3}\qquad\ref{4}\qquad\ref{5}