# Insert labels inside table rows

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, lyx, labels

I have a long table with different equation, I need to make a label and then refer to them in **some** cells, trying to do that by putting usual label giving me wrong results in LyX, more precisely if the table is in some section, strangely enough making a label in some cell, and referencing it somewhere, will make a link not to the cell's label, but to the section title it self.

Below is exported code from LyX to Plain LaTeX:

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A New Section}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\label{eq:Mass Energy}$E=mc^{2}$ & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{centering}

\protect\caption{sample}
\end{table}
A reference to (\ref{eq:Mass Energy})
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if this LyX bug or LaTeX specific, any ideas? (especially by using labels not `hyperref`).

PS:

1. Interestingly, If I totally will remove the section, the output of the reference became empty.
2. There are some similar [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66838) here, like auto numbering with labelling table rows, but that is not what I need.

Comment: are you using `equation` or some other referencable enviornmewnt such as `align` for your mathematics? If you just use `$` or `\[` then the behaviour would be as you describe (whether or not the text is in a table).

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Imentioned in the notes that this is not what I need.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use align on the table it self, not the equation, is it an issue?

Comment: @TMS It is impossible for me to guess what you have done. Every question should have a complete small document that demonstrates the issue, you could edit the question to add a test document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: done, sorry for that, thought it is clear..

Comment: @TMS even when you think it is clear, it is always preferred to post a minimal example. There are other reasons than clarity (see e.g. http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample)

Comment: So as predicted you have _not_ used `align` but simply `$`. `\label` records the last referencable unit, which is the section head in this case. You need to use `equation` or some similar environment to give a referencable number that can be returned by `\ref`. You haven't given any indication of what you want `\ref` to return, so I can't answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\label` records the last referencable item, which is the section head in your case.

Normally to refer to a formula you would use `equation` or `align` but sometimes in tables you can do it "by hand"

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A New Section}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:Mass Energy}$E=mc^{2}$ & (\theequation)\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{centering}

\protect\caption{sample}
\end{table}
A reference to (\ref{eq:Mass Energy})
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe I understood what happened now: when labeling equation directly in LyX it inserting equation environment by it self, but when the equation was inside a table, LyX didn't understand what I'm lebeling there, hence the mess, thank you David.

Comment: Sorry for this, but there is still an issue: when making a formated/textual reference to that equation, it outputs section title "A new section" instade of "Eq. xx", can you please advice how to solve that?