# How to put the label in a table's column

Tags: tables, labels

How to put the label in a table's column, just like this picture.

When I put \caption{aaa} in a column, the document cannot be compiled.

[image]

Comment: this mught be helpful: [Insert labels inside table rows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223847/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following setup provides a way to insert a `\tabularcaption{<cols>}{<colspec>}{<caption>}`. It uses `\multicolumn{<cols>}{<colspec>}{<stuff>}` to insert the appropriate content, formatted the way you specify it using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tabularcaption}[3]{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{#2}{%
    \refstepcounter{table}% Step the table counter
    \captionfont% Set the caption font
    {\captionlabelfont\tablename\ \thetable}% Set the caption label
    \caption@lsep% Set the caption separation
    {\captiontextfont #3}% Set the caption text
    \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}#3}% Add caption to LoT
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Whatever formatting you need for the captions
\captionsetup{%
  font = sl,
  labelfont = bf,
  textfont = it
}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | *{7}{l|} }
    \hline
    \tabularcaption{7}{|l|}{A table} \\
    \hline
    A   & B   & C     & D    & E    & F   & G     \\
    \hline
    1   & 2   & 3     & 4    & 5    & 6   & 7     \\
    One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Ideally one would like to just use something like `\tabularcaption{<caption>}`, but you'd need the flexibility to adjust the caption layout based on the content of the `tabular`. As such, the first two arguments are mandatory, requiring you to specify both the number of columns the caption should span, as well as the column specification/layout.

Answer (score 4):

One solution could be but the caption inside a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{.4\linewidth}{|XXXX|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{
\parbox{.35\linewidth}{\caption{The caption is not 
outside the tabularx environment.}}}\\[2.3em]
\hline
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\
    31 & 32 & 33 & 34\\
    41 & 42 & 43 & 44\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```