# Numbering of Equations in Tabulars and Tabularrays

Tags: equations, numbering, tabularx, tabularray

I tried to list some equations in a table.
I found a working solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66838/206513) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521428/206513) for use with `tabular` (like the first in the MWE below).

However, if I try the same with `tabularray`, the numbers get messed up, probably because `tblr` executes the content code multiple times. Does anyone know a way the prevent this issue? I tried to add `[expand=\Eq]` to the `tblr`, but this had apparently no effect.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Eq}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}

    \noindent\begin{tabular}{lXr}
                 Caption 1 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:1} \\
                 Caption 2 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:2} \\
                 Caption 3 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:3} \\
                 Caption 4 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:4} \\
    \end{tabular}

    \noindent\begin{tblr}{lXr}
                 Caption 1 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:5} \\
                 Caption 2 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:6} \\
                 Caption 3 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:7} \\
                 Caption 4 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:8} \\
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such cases to package `tabularray` is added library `counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, counter}
\newcommand{\Eq}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{lXr}
         Caption 1 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:5} \\
         Caption 2 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:6} \\
         Caption 3 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:7} \\
         Caption 4 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:8} \\
\end{tblr}

or

\begin{tblr}{lX[c]r}
         Caption 1 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:5} \\
         Caption 2 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:6} \\
         Caption 3 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:7} \\
         Caption 4 & $E = mc^2$ & \Eq\label{eq:8} \\
\end{tblr}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]